# How to prevent NavController navigate to another fragment (e.g. cancel navigation)

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have fragment screen build from multiple fragments (tablet layout). I need easy centralised mechanism to prevent leaving screen (e.g. navigate to another destination) by NavController.

I'm using Android navigation component. As I have background in iOS development I'm looking for something like "shallPerformSegue" callback where I can cancel navigation if I decide that something needs to be done first.

Ideally I would like to "do not override NavController". In fact I would love to keep NavController as it is - intact. My ultimate goal is to come up with generic solution that can be reused on another screens if needed.